# How do I change the language for a credit card/paypal payment page in PayPal for a customer?

Tags: html, paypal

When a customer clicks on a button that redirects him to PayPal page when he need to put his card info etc. , this page is in English. Is it possible to change it to different language? E.g. Czech? If yes, how to do that? Could that info be sent within the form input hiddne fields with other informations or in a action link of that form?

UPDATE:
I am using this code on my website:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="****@yahoo.com">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $sesion_qty?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $sesion_prod ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $session_prodid ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $sesion_price ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CZK">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://****.com/test/mem_account/thanks.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://****.com/mem_account/canceled.html">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://****.com/mem_account/ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['order_id']; ?>">
<input type="image" border="0" name="submit" src="http://images.paypal.com/images/x-click-but5.gif" alt="whatihawk product with PayPal">
</form>
```

Comment: Is it possible somehow or not?

Answer (score 2):

How do you display the button exactly ?
Because if you look to this table, https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI0709B__id08A7CI030HS, you'll se that the `lc` parameter aims to do what you would like to do.

Answer (score 0):

Jimmy, there's a localecode option within the API. Can you please let us know which PayPal product you are trying to use, that will help us suggest the right solution

Answer (score 0):

For Express Checkout `localecode`:

```
    &METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
    &RETURNURL=https://...
    &CANCELURL=https://...
    &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=25.00
    &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR
    &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
    &LOCALECODE=ES
```

see: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/

For REST APIS, the adjustment is automatic (users' profile sets the parameter).

(Please vote for the answer if it answers your question)