# How can I set language for paypal sandbox login page?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to display paypal login page based on user locale. How can I do that? I have added localeCode attribute, but it not working. Please go through my code, and correct me if I’m wrong

```
<form:form commandName="paymentForm" id="paymentForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="paypal">           
    <form:input path="cmd" id="cmd" name="cmd" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="business" id="business" name="business" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="password" id="password" name="password" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="custom" id="custom"  name="custom" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="item_name" id="item_name" name="item_name" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="amount"  id="amount" name="amount" type="hidden" />
    <form:input path="currency_code" id="currency_code" type="hidden"/>
    <form:input path="rm"  id="rm" name="rm" type="hidden" />
    <%-- <form:input path="returnUrl"  id="return" name="return" type="hidden" /> --%>
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="${paymentForm.returnUrl}" />      
    <form:input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" path="paymentaction"/>
    <form:input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" path="cancel_return" />
    <form:input type="hidden" name="cert_id" path="certId" />
    <input type="hidden" name="LOCALECODE" value="en_US" />
        </form:form>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/18632731/955855

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the language for a credit card/paypal payment page in PayPal for a customer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630431/how-do-i-change-the-language-for-a-credit-card-paypal-payment-page-in-paypal-for)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="LOCALECODE" value="en_US" />
```

Replace to

```
<input type='hidden' name='LC' value='EN'>
```

for more info see this.

https://www.rocketgranny.com/codeclips/pp_languagecodes.php

Comment: please set value like en_US, en_DE etc not 'EN' only

Answer (score 0):

i have added the following code into my form, now it will working

```
<input name=lc type=hidden value="en_US" />
```